# RegEx help for special characters and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the following:

- No numbers
- Only allow the special characters `-`  and `'`
- Spaces should not be allowed at the beginning or end of the field
- Remove any additional blank space if found between parts of names (allow only one space between parts of name - if multiple middle names)
- Allow diacritics

Chat GPT gave the following:

```
^(?!.*\d)[\p{L}'-]+$
```

However this still allows me to enter consecutive spaces.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then see if you can revise your title to ask a more specific question (to distinguish it from all the other regex questions). Also take the [tour], and have a look at the editor toolbar so you know what tools are available to you for formatting  your post.

Comment: Please do not put questions saying fix what ChatGPT got wrong.

Comment: Instead of chatGPT attempt, you'd better put examples of what should and should not be allowed (or input and output if it is about editing). Also, diacritics are allowed, but what about usual letter? And what about non latin letters, like cyrillic, korean and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like that in JavaScript:

```js
const myString = "Hello    world!  This   is pizza?";

const regex = /^(?!.*\d)[\p{L}'-]+$/g;
const result = myString.replace(regex).replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!

With this expression I'm unable to add a singular space between characters, so for example:

"Joe Bloggs" should be accepted.

Comment: I managed to get it by asking Chat GPT to modify your answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help. Could you mark my answer as correct so it can get the green tick

Comment: `[\p{L}'-]` means either `p`, `{`, `L`, `}`, `'` or `-`. To use unicode properties, enable the [`u` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode). Also, calling `.replace()` without specifying the replacement results in JS adding `undefined` to the string. That is, if your regex does match.

Comment: @InSync If you add "+$" at the end of the regex it does not return `undefined` as it remembers the string value.

Answer (score -2):

OK, found the answer:

```
^(?!.*\d)[\p{L}'-]+(?:\s[\p{L}'-]+)*$
```